# How am I supposed to store user account details data in a decentralized manner?

Tags: solidity, web3js, react, wagmi

I'm building an NFT marketplace app where creators can mint NFTs based on some external images, and users can buy those to support the creators. I need to support user account details storage. I'll need to store things like name, country, etc. How can I do that in a React/Dolpin/Wagmi application? Thanks!

I thought of storing it in a contract, but not sure. As of now I only have one NFT Solidity ERC721 contract.

Comment: If the data is not confidential then you can store it in the contract itself using structs.